# Intermittent error cannot match any routes unit testing Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, router

I've read many posts on the subject about using the router testing module and trying to spy on the router.navigate method but none have resolved the issue I have. Every 2nd run of my tests or so I will see the error, here's the first line in full

```
Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'post/view'
```

To reiterate the error has not been seen when I run my app only when testing

It only appears once no matter how many tests are in the component and it's always the first test that it happens for, if I switch the order then it's the new first test that fails with this error

My component is as follows ( unrelated code removed for brevity )

```js
export class CreatePostComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private postService: PostService,
              private router: Router,
              private location: Location) {
  }

  submitPost() {
    this.validMessage = '';
    if (!this.createPostForm.valid) {
      this.validMessage = 'Please fill out the form before submitting!';
      return;
    }
    const post = this.createPostForm.value as IPost;
    this.postService.createPost(post)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.createPostForm.reset();

          //Here's the call that I believe causes the issues
          this.router.navigate(['post/view']);
        },
        error => {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Here's the spec, again unrelated tests removed

```js
describe('CreatePostComponent', () => {
  let component: CreatePostComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreatePostComponent>;
  let http: HttpTestingController;
  let mockPostService;
  let mockLocationService;


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockPostService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['createPost']);
    mockLocationService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['back']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CreatePostComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {provide: PostService, useValue: mockPostService},
        {provide: Location, useValue: mockLocationService}]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    http = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreatePostComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

I have also tried spying on the router as below (rest of code unchanged)

```js
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockPostService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['createPost']);
    mockLocationService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['back']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CreatePostComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {provide: PostService, useValue: mockPostService},
        {provide: Location, useValue: mockLocationService}]
    })
      .compileComponents();

    spyOn<any>(component['router'], 'navigate').and.returnValue(true);
  }));
```

and I have tried injecting my own mock for navigate as below

```js
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockPostService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['createPost']);
    mockLocationService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['back']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CreatePostComponent],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {provide: PostService, useValue: mockPostService},
        {provide: Location, useValue: mockLocationService},
        {provide: Router, useValue: {navigate: () => true}}]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You did not provide the RouterTestingModule with any valid routes, so it is telling you it has no idea how to route to 'post/view'.  Change your import of RouterTestingModule to something like the following:

```
RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
  { path: 'post/view', component: BlankComponent },
])
```

Where BlankComponent is an empty component just for testing purposes.

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-56092724?file=app%2Fcreate-post.component.spec.ts) showing this solution.  To recreate your error, simply comment out the RouterTestingModule declaration I changed, and uncomment out the original one without routes just below it in the Stackblitz.

I agree the docs are not great on this - the main testing documentation simply states there will be a future document describing the RouterTestingModule in more detail.  See the API info [here](https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule), it gives an example at the end of the usage withRoutes.

I hope this helps.  :)

Comment: Sorry that's my bad, I was originally using the provider like this before I started trying the solutions above to resolve the issue, I was sure I had the withRoutes code in there too. I'll go back to it using your exact example and let you know if it works  and update the question after work

Comment: Did you get to test this out yet?

Comment: Hi sorry I've had to concentrate on another project, I'm going to accept your answer so the bounty isn't lost and I'll get back to this thread with an update when I do get around to it. Thanks for answering!

Comment: How come `spyOn(router, 'navigate')` does not solve this issue ?

Comment: Worked for me, thanks for sharing @dmcgrandle